# Pandas data frame splitting by cycles

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame for the stops & scheduled times of a single transit route throughout a given day. I would like to split this into multiple frames each corresponding to individual trips made by a given bus (based only on the `stop` cycles & not when the `scheduled` periodicity would happen).

For example, the following has two `A->B->C` trips, so looking how to split the frame (ie: at index 3 in this case) such that each sub frame has the same sequence of stops.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "scheduled": ["2023-05-25 13:00", "2023-05-25 13:15", "2023-05-25 13:45", "2023-05-25 14:35", "2023-05-25 14:50", "2023-05-25 15:20"],
    "stop": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"]
})
pd.to_datetime(df["scheduled"])
```

Comment: so you always have A/B/C? if not please generalize

Comment: Unfortunately # of stops is not known or fixed, it's inferred from the schedule chronology. For simplicity, assume all trips have the same # of stops even tho in practice some trips may have extra or fewer stops (ie: rush hour skipping stops)

Comment: Please provide a working example of your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: So you don't know if it is AB, A/B/C or A/B/C/D but it's always the same pattern?

Comment: Correct, assume the stop pattern is the same (unless there is an easy way to relax that in the solution).

Comment: @nicom added the equivalent setup in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't know how many stops you have but that the pattern always repeats, you could compare to the first name and increment every time this stop is found, then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split:

```
group = df['stop'].eq(df['stop'].iloc[0]).cumsum()

out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(group)]
```

Output:

```
[  scheduled stop
 0   1:00 pm    A
 1   1:15 pm    B
 2   1:45 pm    C,
   scheduled stop
 3   2:35 pm    A
 4   2:50 pm    B
 5   3:20 pm    C]
```

Intermediate with the group number:

```
  scheduled stop  group
0   1:00 pm    A      1
1   1:15 pm    B      1
2   1:45 pm    C      1
3   2:35 pm    A      2
4   2:50 pm    B      2
5   3:20 pm    C      2
```

Other option, compute the number of unique stops ([`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html)) and use this to split with [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
import numpy as np

n = df['stop'].nunique()
out = np.array_split(df, range(n, len(df), n))
```

Comment: Both solutions worked great!